# How does AdblockPlus DOM blocking whitelisting works?

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, firefox-addon-sdk, adblock

I am trying to implement similar behaviour. I writing own blocker that behave same way. 
And the DOM blocker in ABP in generally works this way: there is created one global css file with all blocked elements(See `_generateCSSContent` generator function in child/elemHide.js), and attach it to every window as user-defined styles. But there is nothing about whitelisted rules. 
While adding, for example, some domain to whitelist is just creating new whitelist rule for this domain(see in `toggleWhitelist` in appSupport.js). But I can not find where this new rule is affecting some page that way that.
How do domain whitelisting works for DOM blocker?

Comment: I rather doubt this site is going to help you reverse engineer some other product's code.  I'd suggest you review [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Reverse engineer? https://adblockplus.org/source